# Activate Yaru on Ubuntu 18.10 after upgrade?

Tags: themes

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 18.10. However, after the upgrade the Adwaita theme was activated and in the gnome tweak tool I cannot find the new Yaru theme.
Anybody got an idea how to install/activate Yaru? Thanks!

Comment: please show us an attempt of what have you tried with screen shots, error logs etc. Cannot help without showing us what you have tried.

Comment: I tried to: install yaru-theme-gnome-shell (which was already installed), install gnome tweak tool and activate yaru from there. However, no option for yaru theme is shown there.

Comment: I think we should file a bug report, as `yaru` should be activated by default after the upgrade.

Comment: I have filed this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/yaru-theme/+bug/1798984

Answer (score 6):

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install ubuntu-session
sudo apt-get --reinstall install yaru-*
```

Then use Appearance tab in Gnome Tweaks to set Applications, Cursor, Icons, Sound to "Yaru" (note there's also Yaru-dark available for Applications if it suits you)

Answer (score 1):

ok, seems after the upgrade I was missing the ubuntu-session package. Fixed.

Comment: How did you fix it? I don't find Yaru theme too.

Comment: @Ives `sudo apt install ubuntu-session`

Comment: @Zanna I already have it installed.

Comment: @Ives oh hmm sorry... either I misunderstood this answer, or your problem is different

Comment: Zanna, you understood correctly. That command fixed it for me.

Comment: @Ives Maybe try to reinstall the package? sudo apt-get --reinstall install ubuntu-session

Comment: @Simon hmm, still not having it.

Answer (score 1):

had this problem too: tried to reinstall ubuntu-session with no luck.
Had to install yaru-theme-gtk, because on gnome-tweak-tools i can see only the gtk version